# Ionic Table with Checkboxes

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am wondering how to do something similar to this:
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-snipp-for-datatable
in an ionic-angular app without using jQuery.
Thanks.

Comment: Show what you have done so far. This is not a place to have things done for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are your mean select all/none?

```
<ion-checkbox (ionChange)="selectAll()" [(ngModel)]="selectAllChecked"></ion-checkbox>
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="rows">
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.checked"></ion-checkbox>
</ng-template>
//js
public selectAllChecked = false;
public rows=[{},{},{}];
selectAll() {
    if (this.selectAllChecked) {
        this.rows.map(item => item.checked = true);
    } else {
        this.rows.map(item => item.checked = false);
    }
}
```